# FailoverClientConnectionFactory cannot correlate response

Tags: spring, spring-integration

On attempt to put `CachingClientConnectionFactory` inside a `FailoverClientConnectionFactory` I'm facing response correlation issues:

```
2016-05-10 08:06:09.190 ERROR 1031 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for 24b4ad67-3bbf-4468-9cd9-e7c1124413b2:1
2016-05-10 08:06:09.694 ERROR 1031 --- [           main] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Tcp Gateway exception
```

The same happens for `FailoverClientConnectionFactory` with `setSingleUse(true)`.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.4.RELEASE` and creating the factories like this (a full Spring Boot example is at https://github.com/kjrz/failover-caching):

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    // return getCachingFactory(true); // (1)
    // return getFailoverFactory(false); // (2)
    // return getFailoverFactory(true); // (3)
    return getFailoverCachingFactory(true); // (4)
}

private AbstractClientConnectionFactory getCachingFactory(final boolean singleUse) {
    final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpFactory = getTcpFactory(singleUse);
    return getCachingFactory(tcpFactory);
}

private AbstractClientConnectionFactory getFailoverFactory(final boolean singleUse) {
    final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpFactory = getTcpFactory(singleUse);
    return getFailoverFactory(tcpFactory, singleUse);
}

private AbstractClientConnectionFactory getFailoverCachingFactory(final boolean singleUse) {
    final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpFactory = getTcpFactory(singleUse);
    final CachingClientConnectionFactory cachingFactory = getCachingFactory(tcpFactory);
    return getFailoverFactory(cachingFactory, singleUse);
}

private TcpNetClientConnectionFactory getTcpFactory(final boolean singleUse) {
    final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 12345);

    final ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer serializer = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer();
    tcpFactory.setDeserializer(serializer);
    tcpFactory.setSerializer(serializer);

    tcpFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    tcpFactory.setSingleUse(singleUse);

    return tcpFactory;
}

private CachingClientConnectionFactory getCachingFactory(final AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory) {
    final CachingClientConnectionFactory cachingFactory = new CachingClientConnectionFactory(factory, 5);
    factory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    return cachingFactory;
}

private FailoverClientConnectionFactory getFailoverFactory(final AbstractClientConnectionFactory factory,
                                                           final boolean singleUse) {
    final FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverFactory =
            new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(Collections.singletonList(factory));

    failoverFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    failoverFactory.setSingleUse(singleUse);

    return failoverFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting - I see what the problem is, while we have tests for Failover over Cached, they are not in the context of a gateway.

I will open a JIRA issue to resolve this.

In general, though, it's better to wire them the other way around (Caching over Failover).

This works:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private AbstractClientConnectionFactory getCachingFailoverFactory(final boolean singleUse) {
    final TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpFactory = getTcpFactory(singleUse);
    FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverFactory = getFailoverFactory(tcpFactory, singleUse);
    return getCachingFactory(tcpFactory);
}
```

I would also recommend that you make the underlying factories (TCP, FailOver) `@Bean`s as well - that way they will be wired up properly for event publishing and other bean initialization stuff.

[JIRA Issue with link to pull request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4024).

Comment: Cheers Gary, it worked. As for the Bean factories, I'm reading addresses from a DB and then providing them to TCP factories, which in turn form a list provided to Failover factories. In this case I figured the best I can do is tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationContext). The Caching and the Failover are now Beans though.

Comment: Thanks for the update - the original problem is now fixed in 4.2.6